# Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I tried uninstalling and installing email_validator many a times, yet it is showing the same error. Below is the list of installed libraries.

```
pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -----------
blinker         1.7.0
Bootstrap-Flask 2.2.0
click           8.1.7
colorama        0.4.6
dnspython       2.6.0
email-validator 2.1.0.post1
Flask           2.3.2
Flask-WTF       1.2.1
idna            3.6
itsdangerous    2.1.2
Jinja2          3.1.3
MarkupSafe      2.1.5
pip             24.0
setuptools      65.5.0
Werkzeug        3.0.0
WTForms         3.0.1
```

Below is the error message shown.

```
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
                                                             ^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python course\.venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\validators.py", line 393, in __init__
    raise Exception("Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.")
Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.
```

Comment: How are you importing Email? 

For me, the following works:
```from wtforms import StringField```
```from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email```

wtforms=3.0.1